# Angularjs tags not working with ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material

The input only shows as plane html rather than angularjs input material. I cannot find a exact solution for my problem

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
   <div ng-bind-html="text1"></div>
   </div>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAria'
])
.controller('myCntrl',function($scope,$sce){

  var text1=$sce.trustAsHtml("<md-input-container class='md-block' flex-gt-sm><label>To Location</label>"+
    "<input required name='name' ng-model='user.name'></md-input-container>");
   $scope.text1=text1;

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working.

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.12/angular-material.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngSanitize'
])
.controller('myCntrl',function($scope,$sce){

  var text1=$sce.trustAsHtml("<md-input-container class='md-block' flex-gt-sm><label>To Location</label>"+
    "<input required name='name' ng-model='user.name'></md-input-container>");
   $scope.text1=text1;

}).directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
   <div bind-html-compile="text1"></div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am able to get the input, but it is not angular material. I have checked it in firefox and chromium

Comment: @PavanSista You sholud use angular material css file. I have add the css file for the material.

Comment: i request you to execute the snippet in stackoverflow. I have already added the css file. I am getting the input but it is not angularjs material.

Comment: @PavanSista Please check now. I have added the bindHtmlCompile directive.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain me what has been done ?

Comment: @PavanSista Here I have added the template attributes at compile time. So It render all meterial css. But in previously it is added in the run time so it can't able to render the meterial css.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind html from controller like this way, but you are binding your `model` from controller (`ng-model='user.name'`) that is not right way

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAria'
])
.controller('myCntrl',function($scope,$sce){

  var text1="<md-input-container class='md-block' flex-gt-sm><label>To Location</label>"+
    "<input required name='name' ng-model='user.name'></md-input-container>";
   $scope.text1=text1;

})
```

**View**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl">
   <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(text1)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more simple solution without directive.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.12/angular-material.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.12/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngSanitize'
])
.controller('myCntrl',function($scope,$sce,$compile){
    var mc=this;
    mc.addInput=function(){
        var html="<md-input-container class='md-block' flex-gt-sm><label>To Loon</label>"+
    "<input required name='name' ></md-input-container>";
 angular.element(document.getElementById('value')).append($compile(html)($scope));
    }
     });
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCntrl as mc">
    <button ng-click="mc.addInput()">ClickHere</button>
   <div id="value" ></div>
   </div>
</body>
```